What does "little" mean here?
In Barbie (2023), Barbie went to Weird Barbie's to fix her flat feet:

Weird Barbie: That Ken of yours, he is one nice-looking little protein
pot.
Barbie: I guess.

What does "little" mean here?

I'd be pretty sure it's an extremely coarse thinly-veiled reference to oral sex. Barbie is not a kid's movie!

'Little' is a diminutive term, and is sometimes used informally in terms of endearment, like "my little honey bunch" or "he's a little hottie!". It doesn't literally mean "small".
